# Conexão remota com PostgreSQL só funciona após PING

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql, ubuntu, lado-do-servidor

Tenho uma aplicação JAVA executando em um servidor e o banco de dados executando em outro.

Os dois servidores estão ligados e na mesma rede, o postgreSQL está habilitado pra receber conexões externas.

Porém quando tento realizar a conexão ao banco de dados a partir da máquina da aplicação, recebo o erro de conexão recusada. Mas é só eu dar um ping a partir do servidor do banco de dados para a maquina da aplicação que a conexão passa a funcionar.

Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo e a solução desse problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: O cliente (aplicação) e o servidor `PostgresSQL` estão no mesmo segmento de rede ? Tem certeza absoluta que não existe um *firewall* e/ou um *roteador* entre o cliente e o servidor ? Qual é o sistema operacional do servidor onde roda o `PostgreSQL` ? O servidor onde roda o `PostgreSQL` possui algum tipo de serviço de *firewall* habilitado ? `SELinux` habilitado ? `firewalld` habilitado ? Alguma regra de `iptables` ?

Comment: P: O cliente (aplicação) e o servidor PostgresSQL estão no mesmo segmento de rede ? 
R: Sim!
P: Tem certeza absoluta que não existe um firewall e/ou um roteador entre o cliente e o servidor ? 
R: Não tenho acesso ao roteador, mas executei o nmap a partir do cliente e tive o seguinte resultado:

`PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
445/tcp  closed microsoft-ds
8080/tcp open   http-proxy`

Parece que existe alguma regra bloqueando, mas no iptables não existe nenhuma regra.

O sistema operacional das duas maquinas é UBUNTU 16.04.

SELinux e firewalld não estão habilitados

Comment: Porta 80!? O `PostgreSQL` não costuma escutar nesta porta, por padrão a porta é a `5432`. Entre em contato com o administrador do roteador/firewall e garanta que o cliente (aplicação) é capaz de se conectar a porta `5432` do servidor (PostgresSQL). Se há um roteador/firewall por aí, é possivel que o cliente/servidor não estejam na mesma rede.

Comment: Pois é...o PostgreSQL está sendo executado na porta 5432 mesmo. Mas o estranho é que após eu realizar um ping do servidor do banco de dados para a maquina da aplicação tudo funciona normalmente. Eu estou achando isso bizarro.. Vou entrar em contato com o responsável, como sugerido. Se o problema for esse mesmo volto aqui pra avisar.

Comment: Esse comportamento é bém típico de um firewall/roteador. É como se "algo" autorizasse a conexão do cliente ao servidor pois assumiu que o servidor "conhece" o cliente devido a tentativa de ping.